# Create a APP named admin in my project whether will get unknown conflict?

Tags: python, django

The django have a default module named admin.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The red frame is created app by myself.

Can I create a APP named `admin` in my project?
I means if I do this, whether in the future I will get some unknown conflict？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because django has app named by `admin` also, so you must choose another name. eg: `app_admin`, `administration`, or else.

Checkout this source: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib

Comment: I have created the APP, but how can I change the name now?

Comment: just rename it.. and change all imported names that already you using from _(admin)_ to _(newappname)_..